# wordpress: how to set up a custom URL AJAX API

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to implement a custom JSON API upon Wordpress, like `/api3/get_posts`, I refer to the implementation of plugin [JSON-API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/), but it just doesn't work. Below is my code:

```
$myPluginBase = 'api3';

function my_plugin_init() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'my_plugin_rewrites');
    add_action('template_redirect', 'my_plugin_template_rewrite');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function my_plugin_template_rewrite(){
    global $myPluginBase;
    if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $myPluginBase ] ) ){
        echo $_REQUEST[ $myPluginBase ];
        exit;
    }
}

function my_plugin_activation() {
    // Add the rewrite rule on activation
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'my_plugin_rewrites');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function my_plugin_deactivation() {
    // Remove the rewrite rule on deactivation
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function my_plugin_rewrites($wp_rules) {
    global $myPluginBase;
    if (empty($base)) {
        return $wp_rules;
    }
    $my_plugin_rules = array(
        "$myPluginBase\$" => "index.php?{$myPluginBase}=info",
        "$myPluginBase/(.+)\$" => "index.php?{$myPluginBase}=\$matches[1]"
    );
    return array_merge($my_plugin_rules, $wp_rules);
}

// Add initialization and activation hooks
add_action('init', 'my_plugin_init');
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation');
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_deactivation');
```

It seems like the `template_redirect` action works, as I open `/api3=hello`, the server will send `hello` back. But if I try to open `/api3/hello`, it keeps showing me the home page.

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but the official REST API is found here http://v2.wp-api.org/ . The API has been implemented into the core of WordPress, the plugin is used for endpoints.